# regular expression for international telephone

Tags: java, regex

I searched endlessly for a regular expression that only matches the international telephone number like this: +436604433839. However, when I add my constraint with

```
@Pattern(regexp = "\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)\d{1,14}$", message = "invalid phone")
```

I get a compile error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the compile error?

Comment: For strings in Java, you have to escape your literal backslashes with a backslash.

Comment: can you please explain us exact compilation error so that we can help you

Comment: I get these one: `Syntax error on tokens. Invalid escape sequence.`

Comment: @anubhava It's not in the regex, it's an attribute from the annotation `@Pattern`

Comment: @user3475602 For future reference, if you'd Googled this error message you would have found countless sites with the answer. Down-vote from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Strings you have to escape a `\` with `\\`.

E.g.

```
String regex = "\d+";
```

becomes

```
String regex = "\\d+";
```

A single `\` is used to escape special characters like new lines or tabs (e.g. `\n` or `\t`).